# Jasmine Wait for Observable Subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine

I have the following class:

```js
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  private subscriptions: { [key: string]: Subscription } = {};

  constructor(private otherService: OtherService) {
  }

  public launchTimer(order: any): void {
    this.subscriptions[order.id] = timer(500, 300000).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.otherService.notify();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to write a unit test which asserts that when **launchTimer()** is called, the **notify** method of **OtherService** is called.
The tricky thing about this is that the subscription to the **timer** observable is done directly in the method which means I can't do the subscription directly in the unit test to do the assertion.
What I came up with so far is the following test which is failing because the assertion is done before the subscription is made:

```js
class OtherServiceMock {
  public notify(): void {}
}

describe('MyService', () => {
  let otherService: OtherServiceMock;
  let myService: MyService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: OtherService, useClass: OtherServiceMock },
      ],
    });
    otherService = TestBed.get(OtherService);
    myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
  });

  it('launchTimer should call notify', () => {
    spyOn(otherService, 'notify');
    myService.launchTimer();
    expect(otherService.notify).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I tried to wrap the function with **async** and I also used **fakeAsync** with **tick** but nothing seems to work.
Any ideas how I can wait for the subscription before making the assertion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing observables with interval and timer can be tricky but try this, if this doesn't work, I can maybe do it a different way as well.

```js
class OtherServiceMock {
  public notify(): void {}
}

describe('MyService', () => {
  let otherService: OtherServiceMock;
  let myService: MyService;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: OtherService, useClass: OtherServiceMock },
      ],
    });
    otherService = TestBed.get(OtherService);
    myService = TestBed.get(MyService);
  });

  it('launchTimer should call notify', fakeAsync(() => {
    // you're going to have to make `subscriptions` public for this to work !!
    spyOn(otherService, 'notify'); // don't need to callThrough to see if it was called or not
    myService.launchTimer({id: 1});
    tick(501);
    expect(otherService.notify).toHaveBeenCalled();
    myService.subscriptions['1'].unsubscribe(); // kill the timer subscription
  }));
});
```

===================== Edit ===================================

You are either going to have to make `subscriptions` public or provide a public way to unsubscribe from a subscription in that object.

Comment: no this doesn't work. I already tried using fakeAsync and tick(). I get this error in this case: 1 periodic timer(s) still in the queue, which makes sense because the subscription is done, but the test times out because I'm using a timer here

Comment: I have made an edit, try it that way. I followed this post btw: https://medium.com/@andrew.nguyenvo/karma-testing-the-rxjs-timer-b490ee7bbfe

Comment: When you get the "timer(s) still in the queue" message, increase the tick() time by a higher amount. For example, if your total time is 500ms, do a tick for 5000ms.